# Do i need Nginx for production use, can i just use Nodejs server instead?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've countered some projects that use Nginx for their production mode, and I'm curious why would they use Nginx as their front end server instead of pure Nodejs like express? is there a significant difference between them? Is it faster and more secure using Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of traffic you expect on your website and what type of application your website is. For a small, simple, low traffic personal site, express should probably be fine. Nginx has more features for load balancing and high performance.  See other answers here: [What's the better approach: serving static files with Express or nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796056/whats-the-better-approach-serving-static-files-with-express-or-nginx)