# Add static middleware to serve static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have the following folder structure:

```
/app
    server.js
/public
    1.jpg
```

I want to be able to access the 1.jpg image from the URI `/1.jpg`.
In my `server.js` file, I added the following middleware at the top:

```
app.use('/', express.static('../public'));
```

and in the buttom i have a middleware that catch not found routes:

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: `Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`
    });
});
```

When i make a request to: /1.jpg i got the following response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Can't find /1.jpg on this server!"
}
```

Even if it should serve the first middleware which is the image

Comment: Not really related, but in production build, [it's better to serve static file using nginx / apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796116/12397250)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be caused by the relative path to the `public` directory because the path is relative to the directory from where you launch your app.

If this is the case, then providing the absolute path should fix it:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
```